# How to calculate each day downtime(total average lightsoff duration) aggregations based on UserId in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I implemented a query based on userid matching the status getting the Lights of received date and lights on received date

```
 Light.aggregate([
      {"$match":{"STATUS":"LIGHTS OFF"}},
      {"$group":{
        "_id":"$SWITCHID",
        "TOTALLIGHTSOFFRECEVEDDATE":{"$push":"$RECEIVEDDATE"},
      }}
    ],

    Light.aggregate([
      {"$match":{"STATUS":"LIGHTS ON"}},
      {"$group":{
        "_id":"$SWITCHID",
        "TOTALLIGHTSONRECEVEDDATE":{"$push":"$RECEIVEDDATE"},
      }}
    ],

    output is:
    {
        "_id" : "Z5-W58-58-1A/12/5",
        "TOTALLIGHTSOFFRECIVEDDATE" : [
            "2018-02-09-06.00.04.846000",
            "2018-02-09-06.15.36.520000",
            "2018-02-09-06.44.44.950000",
            "2018-02-09-07.14.49.457000",
            "2018-02-09-07.44.54.994000",
            "2018-02-09-08.14.56.890000",

        ]
    }
    {
        "_id" : "Z5-W63-199A/6",
        "TOTALLIGHTSOFFRECIVEDDATE" : [
            "2018-02-09-05.51.37.082000",
            "2018-02-09-06.27.34.869000",
            "2018-02-09-06.56.45.592000",
            "2018-02-09-07.26.49.401000",
            "2018-02-09-07.56.53.023000",
            "2018-02-09-08.26.57.172000",

        ]
    }
    {
        "_id" : "Z5-W58-58-1A/12/5",
        "TOTALLIGHTSONRECIVEDDATE" : [
            "2018-02-09-00.58.57.801000",
            "2018-02-09-00.28.52.478000",
            "2018-02-09-01.29.21.811000",
            "2018-02-09-01.59.05.749000",
            "2018-02-09-02.29.10.715000",
            "2018-02-09-02.59.13.542000",
            "2018-02-09-03.29.18.677000",
            "2018-02-09-03.59.23.692000",

        ]
    }
    {
        "_id" : "Z5-W63-199A/6",
        "TOTALLIGHTSONRECIVEDDATE" : [
            "2018-02-09-00.50.54.233000",
            "2018-02-09-00.20.48.378000",
            "2018-02-09-01.20.57.603000",
            "2018-02-09-01.51.39.090000",
            "2018-02-09-02.21.06.288000",
            "2018-02-09-02.51.11.159000",
            "2018-02-09-03.21.15.296000",

        ]
    }
```

How to get the values from received lightsOn duration to received
 lightsOff average duration in each ID .can anyone suggest me how to
 resolve this issue.

Comment: my expected response is each id total lights off duration @Veeram

Comment: Can you show in it json format ? Also explain how to calculate average value ? Please add all updates to post.

Comment: my requirement is  for day each swichId   48 times some time off and some time on how to get only total off time duration with eachid  please suggest me Veeram sir how to resolve this issuse @Veeram

Comment: so for ex what will be expected  total time off value for  "_id" : "Z5-W58-58-1A/12/5" ? Please add all your updates to question.

Comment: for ex this is my fields: same day
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a8bab026c44f9d64085a2be"),
    "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/4",
    "TOTALSTREETLIGHTS" : 22,
    "WORKINGSTREETLIGHTS" : 22,
    "CUMULATIVEKWH" : 257.39,
    "STATUS" : "LIGHTS ON",
    "LATITUDE" : 17.7429,
    "LONGITUDE" : 83.2542,
    "RECEIVEDDATE" : "2018-02-09-00.12.17.494000",
    "OFFICE_ID" : "200-84",
    "FLAG2" : "K",
    "CREATE_DATE" : "2018-02-09-00.04.06.952000"
}

Comment: for ex this is my fields: same day
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a8bab026c44f9d64085a2be"),
    "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/4",
    "TOTALSTREETLIGHTS" : 22,
    "WORKINGSTREETLIGHTS" : 22,
    "CUMULATIVEKWH" : 257.39,
    "STATUS" : "LIGHTS ON",
    "LATITUDE" : 17.7429,
    "LONGITUDE" : 83.2542,
    "RECEIVEDDATE" : "2018-02-09-00.12.17.494000",
    "OFFICE_ID" : "200-84",
    "FLAG2" : "K",
    "CREATE_DATE" : "2018-02-09-00.04.06.952000"
}
same each Swichid every day 48 times,  Status some time off some time on  how to get each swichid lights off duration(down time)@Veeram

Comment: How do you calculate light time off duration ? Is it a difference between values in two light off documents ? Or light on and light off document. Please give me expected output json for some id and add details to question. I'll take a look little later.

Comment: based on the created _date everyday time difference between 12 hours

Comment: based on the created _date everyday time difference between 12 hours @Veeram sir

Comment: [ {SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/4, duration: 7}, {SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/5, duration: 5}]  
Finding difference in two timestamp CREATE_DATEtimestamp and RECEIVEDDATEtimestamp @Veeram sir